# Reaction of 2,3-dichlorobutanoate with a decarboxylating agent followed by hydrochloric acid and then aq. potassium hydroxide

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds, halides, hydrocarbons

#### Question

> $$\ce{CH3-CH(Cl)-CH(Cl)-COO- ->[-CO2]A->[HCl]B->[aq KOH]C}$$ Product C is:
>
> a) $\ce{CH3-CH2-CHO}$
>
> b) $\ce{CH3-CH(OH)-CH2-CH2-OH}$
>
> c) $\ce{CH3-CHO}$
>
> d)$\ce{CH3-C(=O)-CH3}$

#### Answer

> The answer given is (a)

#### My attempt

[image]

[image]

[image]

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: the addition of HCL youve done to alkene is wrong , it will be geminal not vicinal there by making ans (a)

Comment: The answer is a) as long a propionaldehyde can avoid an aldol condensation in the presence of aqueous KOH. c) can't be the answer. Do the math on the number of carbons.

Comment: Yeah the answer is A my bad( i will edit it). But why where would the H+ attack(in the 2nd step)? I thought as i did because Cl- would make C+ unstable?

Comment: Also can someone advice me how to convert pictures to text like the above text ? I will try to make my questions better.

Comment: Shreya why would it be geminal ?

Comment: @AdityaSURESH check this out-https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here  for writing molecules on here or else you can use online softwares to draw molecules

Comment: See [here](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized) and [here](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here?noredirect=1&lq=1). For a more detailed MathJax guide, look [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), [minor other details](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3044/hidden-points-of-editing-you-probably-didnt-know?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: (continued) To draw chemical compounds, [this](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3736/how-do-i-draw-chemical-compounds-and-chemical-reaction-mechanisms-and-add-it-to/3737#3737) should help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the follow up doubt, why geminal and not vicinal?
[image: geminal di halide formation]

the carbocation formed is more stable because of $\ce{Cl}$ **+M.**

Comment: also make sure you dont use this logic anywhere else, this is an observation specific as theres +M and -I continuously fighting.